# Path issue with jQuery plugin in Grails 2.4.4

Tags: jquery, grails

I'm having a bit of trouble getting the jQuery plugin working with Grails 2.4.4. This seems like it should be an easy setup, but when I start my application with grails run-app, I see this message

| Error 2014-12-07 12:38:06,397 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /plugins/jquery-1.11.1/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js

In looking into the "target" directory on the file system, I do see a "jquery-1.11.1" directory under the "plugins" directory with the jquery-1.11.1.min.js file, although it is located in the "webapp" directory. Here is the relevant portion of my BuildConfig file, any help would be much appreciated.

```
plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.8'
    compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"

    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
    runtime ":resources:1.2.13"

    // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
    //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
    //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
    //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
    //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, false alarm on this one. It was an issue with the way I had the resources plugin configured. Apologies for the newbie mistake.

Comment: You need to choose one of asset-pipeline and resources, and remove the other. They do the same thing.

Comment: Hmmm... actually this is not resolved. I did remove the asset-pipeline and left everything else the same. I'm still getting an error saying 
"Resource not found: /plugins/jquery-1.11.1/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js." Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: Both plugins rewrite the names and/or locations of the files as part of the work they do. Read the plugin docs for the syntax of the taglib that you use to render the correct urls for resources